# .htaccess RewriteRule also affects other files with the same name?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect http://www.domain.com/cart to http://www.domain.com/cart.php with:

```
RewriteRule cart cart.php [L]
```

That works, but I just noticed that it also redirects files named `http://www.domain.com/images/cart.jpg` to the same page.

How can I avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use start and end anchors in your rule to target only `/cart` or `/cart/` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^cart/?$ cart.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: I just noticed that when I access http://www.domain.com/cart it works, but when accessing http://www.domain.com/cart/ it is still in an endless 404 loop. Any ideas?

Comment: This should work for `/cart` and `/cart/` both. Try adding `Options -MultiViews` on top of your .htaccess